# How to update configuration in any environments in urban code using rest call?

Tags: websphere, spring-restcontroller, rest-client, udeploy, urbancode

I am trying to create rest api to update configuration in all environments in urban code.
Is there any rest client or do we need write any custom code.?

How do I start? Your kind suggestions please

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about updating environment properties?  If so.  I do this with Powershell.

```
$webUrl = "https://ibm-ucd.myCompany.com"
$ucdApiUserName = "yourCLIAccount"
$ucdApiPass = "yourCLIpassword"
$appName = "MyApplication"
$environment = "ADT"
$propertyNewValue = "myNewValue"
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($ucdApiUserName,(ConvertTo-SecureString $ucdApiPass -AsPlainText -Force))

####################################################################
## Bypass Cert Issues with connecting to HTTPS API
####################################################################
$certData = [string][System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy
if ($certData -ne "TrustAllCertsPolicy")
{
    add-type @"
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
public bool CheckValidationResult(
ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
return true;
}
}
"@
    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
}

$hash = [ordered] @{
"application"   = "$AppName";
"environment"   = "$environment";
"isSecure"      = "false";
"name"          = "myEnvProperty";
"value"         = "$propertyNewValue"
}

$newValuesJson = $hash | ConvertTo-Json
Write-Host "Updating uDeploy environment properties for $environment"
$uri = "$WebUrl/cli/environment/propValue?"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'PUT' -ContentType "application/json" -Credential 
$credential -uri $uri -Body $newValuesJson | Out-Null
```